# Scrolling activity lagging when i add an ImageView

Tags: android, scroll, lag, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an issue with collapsing toolbar layout (android's library) .
Eveything works fine until i add an `imageview` in the `content_scrolling.xml` file
it start lagging when collapsing can you please help me.
this is the `activity_scrolling.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.hamza.collapsingprofile.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the `content_scrolling.xml` file with the `imageview` that i want to add with `id=user_profile_photo` if i delete the imageview it scrolls fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hamza.collapsingprofile.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/hamza" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="Viral Android"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_short_bio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Android free tutorials and example"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile XMl UI Design" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile XMl UI Design" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when my image for ImageView has been placed in 'drawable' folder. When I place it in 'drawable-nodpi' everything was fine.

Comment: This. I had this issue. Move images to xxxhdpi works well on my xxxhdpi device